# upload progress div increase

Tags: ajax, upload, progress-bar

```
 function uploadToServer(){
fileField = document.getElementById("uploadedFile");
var fileToUpload = fileField.files[0]; 
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var uploadStatus = xhr.upload;
 uploadStatus.addEventListener("progress", function (ev) {
        if (ev.lengthComputable) {
            $("#uploadPercentage").html((ev.loaded / ev.total) * 100 + "%");
        }
    }, false);

uploadStatus.addEventListener("error", function (ev) {$("#error").html(ev)}, false);
uploadStatus.addEventListener("load", function (ev) {$("#error").html("sorry!")}, false);

xhr.open(
        "POST",
        "serverUpload.php",
        true
        );
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", fileToUpload.fileName);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", fileToUpload.fileSize);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", fileToUpload.type);
    //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    xhr.send(fileToUpload);
```

}

$(function(){

```
$("#uploadButton").click(uploadToServer);
```

});

`

```
<form action="" name="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

hi this code is working fine. but i need increase div size. but this one only showing percentage only. what i have to change to get dat one.

Answer (score 0):

bellow is simple progressbar code using HTML5

```
<progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
<span id="status"></span>
<h1 id="finalMessage"></h1>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function progressBarSim(al) {
   var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
   var status = document.getElementById('status');
   status.innerHTML = al+"%";
   bar.value = al;
   al++;
   var sim = setTimeout("progressBarSim("+al+")",300);
   if(al == 100){
  status.innerHTML = "100%";
  bar.value = 100;
  clearTimeout(sim);
  var finalMessage = document.getElementById('finalMessage');
  finalMessage.innerHTML = "Process is complete";
}
   }
  var amountLoaded = 0;
  progressBarSim(amountLoaded);
 </script>
```

it may help you, fix this code in your coding.

Comment: thanks jay. but i m new to jquery.so m unable to fix dis in dat one. i did but it's not coming well.

Comment: code which i gave u, its working fine. just copy whole code and paste it in new file with .html extension and run it. it will give u result. and later u put this script section inside your code. and in html body part put progress element.